# ignore specific file when running git stash show -p

Tags: git

I would like to not see the output of package-lock.json when running `git stash show -p`. Variants of this did not work: `g stash show -p -D -- . ':(exclude)package-lock.json'`. Thanks

Comment: [`git stash show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-show-u--include-untracked--only-untrackedltdiff-optionsgtltstashgt) doesn't accept pathspec. [<pathspec>](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-ltpathspecgt82308203) is only valid for *push* command.

Comment: so it is not possible to ignore a file with git stash show using the options git provides?

Comment: I think it's impossible.

Comment: OK, thank you @phd

Comment: it is possible - see answer by @LeGEC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stash is actually a commit (a merge commit to be precise), pointed to by an actual ref (`refs/stash`).

So you can use : `git show stash`, and all options relative to `git show` itself :

```
git show stash -- . ':(exclude)package-lock.json'
```

---

The "past stashes" (the ones listed in `git stash list`) are actually entries in the reflog for `stash`, so you can also work with `git show stash@{1}`, `git show stash@{2}`, etc ...